# Can we use the pvlib inverter functions for modelling a DC-DC converter for battery storage systems?

Tags: battery, pvlib

I want to model bidirectional converters (PCS) and DC-DC converters for BESS systems. Can I use the existing functions in PVLib?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Although the core converter losses are similar for the different types of converters, it would be hard to identify a suitable parameter set in the inverter database and you would have to be quite creative in your program to accommodate power flows in different directions.